# DRF: Which if better to create custom structure of response in Serializer/ModelSerializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am currently making a simple `CRUD` application on `Django Rest Framework`.

I need to return a response to the client for any request in a specific structure.

For example, if a client makes a `POST` request to create a new record and it was executed successfully, then API needs to return such structure:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "bobmarley@gmail.com",
        }
    ],
    "error": {}
}
```

Let's say the problem is related to the model field. In this case, the API should return such a structure:

```
{
    "data": [],
    "error": {
        "email": [
            "This field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

If the problem is not related to the model field, then it is necessary to return to the client such a structure where there would be a description of the error:

```
{
    "data": [],
    "error": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Description of the error."
        ]
    }
}
```

Depending on the error, I also have to return different statuses in the query responses.

**openapi-schema.js:**

```
  /clients:
    post:
      summary: Create New Client
      operationId: post-clients
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Client Created
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Result'
              examples: {}
        '400':
          description: Missing Required Information
        '409':
          description: Email Already Taken
```

My current code returns an incorrect structure. Should I configure all this at the serialization level?

```
{
    "data": [],
    "error": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "{'email': [ErrorDetail(string='person with this email already exists.', code='unique')]}"
        ]
    }
}
```

**models.py:**

```
class Client(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "clients"

def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
```

**views.py:**

```
class ClientView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = []
        error = {}
        result = {"data": data, "error": error}
        try:
            client_serializer = ClientSerializer(data=request.data)
            client_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            client_serializer.save()
            data.append(client_serializer.data)
            return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except Exception as err:
            error['non_field_errors'] = [str(err)]
            return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return response data as you want.

```
class ClientView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = []
        error = {}
        result = {"data": data, "error": error}

        try:
            client_serializer = ClientSerializer(data=request.data)

            if not client_serializer.is_valid():
                result["error"] = client_serializer.errors
                return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            client_serializer.save()
            data.append(client_serializer.data)
            result["data"] = data
            return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        except Exception as err:
            result["data"] = []
            result["error"] = "Something went wrong"
            return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. In my post, I pointed out a small piece of the `openapi.json` file with documentation on a `POST` request. It turns out that if the client forgot to specify the email field in the `Request Body`, the error code `400` is returned. If the email already exists, then you need to return `409`. Now the 400 code is returned for both of these cases. What can I do to return the correct status code in the second case?

Comment: While validating in your serializer raise a customexception EmailAlreadyExists and then catch the exectpion in your API and in the response send your requried status.

Answer (score 0):

it depends your side

```
{
    "data": [],
    "error": {
        "email": [
            "This field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

I have to say this sometimes wrong because errors could be different, I mean, there could be string validations, country based checking or others.

I suggest this code

```
{
    "data": [],
    "error": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            {'email': [ErrorDetail(string='person with this email already exists.', code='unique')]}
        ]
    }
}
```

another case you can get errors and manually send them to client side, like:

```
client_serializer = ClientSerializer(data=request.data) 
if client_serializer.is_valid(): 
    return client_serializer.save() 
else: 
    return {"errors": client_serializer.errors}
```

Comment: For example, if some fields in the Request Body were omitted during the POST request, then the first option should be returned. My current code returns the second option which is not correct in my case. Do you have any ideas of what I need to change?

Comment: did you try serializers errors:

Comment: client_serializer = ClientSerializer(data=request.data)
if client_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
    return client_serializer.save()
else:
    return {"errors": client_serializer.errors}